# How to add DOI to latex references?

Tags: bibtex, doi, apacite

Consider the following latex document:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% % Title and author
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{\textbf{My title}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    First citation: \cite{Tibshirani1996b}, second citation \cite{Laria2019a}.
    \bibliography{D:/Documentos_2/GoogleDrive/Doctorado/Tesis/Articulos/library}
\end{document}
```

Where the cited entries have the following bibtex structure:

```
@article{Laria2019a,
author = {Laria, Juan C. and Aguilera-Morillo, M. Carmen and Lillo, Rosa E.},
doi = {10.1080/10618600.2019.1573687},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Documentos{\_}2/GoogleDrive/Doctorado/Tesis/Bibliograf{\'{i}}a/Mendeley/An iterative sparse-group lasso{\_}Laria, Aguilera-Morillo, Lillo{\_}2019.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics},
month = {feb},
pages = {1--21},
title = {{An iterative sparse-group lasso}},
url = {https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10618600.2019.1573687},
year = {2019}
}

@article{Tibshirani1996b,
author = {Tibshirani, Robert},
doi = {10.2307/2346178},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Documentos{\_}2/GoogleDrive/Doctorado/Tesis/Bibliograf{\'{i}}a/Mendeley/Regression Shrinkage and Selection via the Lasso{\_}Tibshirani{\_}1996.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological)},
number = {1},
pages = {267--288},
publisher = {WileyRoyal Statistical Society},
title = {{Regression Shrinkage and Selection via the Lasso}},
url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346178},
volume = {58},
year = {1996}
}
```

Now if I compile the document, I obtain this output:
[image]

As you can see, both bibtex entries have doi, but this is not shown in the latex document. I would like to use if possible apalike style for the bibliography (ibcluding the DOI), but I read that apacite includes the DOI in the references, so I tried using it:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{apacite}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% % Title and author
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{\textbf{My title}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    First citation: \cite{Tibshirani1996b}, second citation \cite{Laria2019a}.
    \bibliography{D:/Documentos_2/GoogleDrive/Doctorado/Tesis/Articulos/library}
\end{document}
```

However, I obtained the following error:

```
Use of \@year@ doesn't match its definition. First citation: \cite{Tibshirani1996b}
Use of \@year@ doesn't match its definition. ...i1996b}, second citation \cite{Laria2019a}
```

### EDIT:

Based on the answers, I have updated the tex file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addbibresource{library.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% % Title and author
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{My title}

\author{Some author}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    First citation: \cite{Tibshirani1996b}, second citation \cite{Laria2019a}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

While compiling this tex file, it returns three error messages:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

And the pdf result does not include any reference section. Do you have any idea on what the reason may be? Regarding the biber vs bibtex question, I do not know what the differences between biber and bibtex are, I am using bibtex because I handle my bibliography using Jabref, and I think it works with bibtex, but maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: `apalike.sty` is very old.  You should probably look at the `apa` style for `biblatex`.

Comment: `apalike` style is one of the earlier BibTeX styles and dates back to the late eighties, when DOIs and even URLs weren't really a thing yet. The style does not support dedicated `url` or `doi` fields. Note that certainly today `apalike` is only *like* APA and would not satisfy the requirements of the APA style. `apacite` on the other hand, aims at implementing the APA requirements as far as possible with BibTeX. If you use `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` you should also load `\usepackage{apacite}`. ...

Comment: ... If you are up for using `biblatex`, you can also get APA style with `biblatex-apa`. Many people who use `apalike` would probably be happy with a less complex style like `biblatex`'s standard `authoryear` style already, so you need not use `apa` if you don't need full APA support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use the ancient `bibtex`. Use instead `biber` which is already installed with your tex distribution:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}% Only for demo here
\begin{filecontents*}{library.bib}
@article{Laria2019a,
    author = {Laria, Juan C. and Aguilera-Morillo, M. Carmen and Lillo, Rosa E.},
    doi = {10.1080/10618600.2019.1573687},
    file = {:D$\backslash$:/Documentos{\_}2/GoogleDrive/Doctorado/Tesis/Bibliograf{\'{i}}a/Mendeley/An 
    iterative sparse-group lasso{\_}Laria, Aguilera-Morillo, Lillo{\_}2019.pdf:pdf},
    journal = {Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics},
    month = {feb},
    pages = {1--21},
    title = {{An iterative sparse-group lasso}},
    url = {https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10618600.2019.1573687},
    year = {2019}
}

@article{Tibshirani1996b,
    author = {Tibshirani, Robert},
    doi = {10.2307/2346178},
    file = 
    {:D$\backslash$:/Documentos{\_}2/GoogleDrive/Doctorado/Tesis/Bibliograf{\'{i}}a/Mendeley/Regression 
    Shrinkage
     and Selection via the Lasso{\_}Tibshirani{\_}1996.pdf:pdf},
    journal = {Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological)},
    number = {1},
    pages = {267--288},
    publisher = {WileyRoyal Statistical Society},
    title = {{Regression Shrinkage and Selection via the Lasso}},
    url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346178},
    volume = {58},
    year = {1996}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\title{\textbf{My title}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    First citation: \cite{Tibshirani1996b}, second citation \cite{Laria2019a}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

run it with `pdflatex <file>`, `biber <file>`, `pdflatex <file>`

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I have tried to use your solution however the references section is not being generated. Please find more information on the edit of the question

Comment: You have to run `biber` and _not_  `bibtex`

Answer (score 1):

I'm new on Latex and I have the same problem with this version of apalike. Apparently, this version is apalike2.bst and, as someone said in another comment, this version is too old. Fortunately, there's a new version, apalike3.bst, which includes doi and url fields. I'm using Natbib (I'm not sure if it works with Biblatex) and I'm using Overleaf, so I upload the file .bst what you can download on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ryzBhGzrK0MKEvziX9FzbLPRqgVvtLx8/view?usp=share_link

and did \bibliographystyle{apalike3.bst} and DOI appeared. So, please, whoever reads my message, corrects my errors or says if it is a reliable solution. I already said it, I'm new to latex, so I can't say it's something that solves the problem. Cheers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/241256)

Comment: Please don't use external links that will break in the future, making the answer useless. EIther find a stable link (to CTAN for example) or explain what changes are in this specific version of the file.